# is it possible to use np arrays as indices in h5py datasets?

Tags: numpy, h5py

I need to merge a number of datasets, each contained in a separate file, into another dataset belonging to a final file.
The order of the data in the partial dataset is not preserved when they get copied in the final one - the data in the partial datasets is 'mapped' into the final one through indices. I created two lists, final_indices and partial_indices, and wrote:

```
final_dataset   = final_hdf5file['dataset']
partial_dataset = partial_hdf5file['dataset']

# here partial ad final_indices are lists.
final_dataset[final_indices] = partial_dataset[partial_indices]
```

the problem with this is that the performance is quite bad - and the reason is that final_ and partial_indices have both to be lists.
my workaround has been to create two np arrays from the final and partial datasets, and use np arrays as indices.

```
final_array   = np.array(final_dataset)
partial_array = np.array(partial_dataset)
# here partial ad final_indices are nd arrays.
final_array[final_indices] = partial_array[partial_indices]
```

The final array is then re-written to the final dataset.

```
final_dataset[...] = final_array
```

However, it seems to me rather inelegant to do so.

Is it possible to use np.arrays as indices in a h5py dataset?

Answer (score 1):

So you are doing fancy-indexing for both the read and write:

http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#fancy-indexing

It warns that it can be slow with long lists.

I can see where reading and writing the whole sets, and doing the mapping on arrays will be faster, though I haven't actually tested that.  The read/writing is faster, as is the mapping

http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#reading-writing-data

I would use the slice notation (or `value`) to load the datasets, but that's a minor point.

```
final_array   = final_dataset[:]
```

Hide the code in a function if it looks inelegant.

This oneliner might work (I haven't tested it).  The RHS is more likely to work.

```
final_dataset[:][final_indices] = partial_dataset[:][partial_indices]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and the links - my experience has been indeed that fancy indexing is slow. Did not try your solution yet, but looks more compact than mine while applying the same principle.