# A quick way to randomly read many rows of a large numpy matrix with h5py

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I'd like to read 2048 randomly chosen rows of a stored numpy matrix of column size 200 within 100ms. So far I've tried with h5py. In my case, contiguous mode works faster than chunks, and for various other reasons I'm trying with the former. Writing (in a certain more orderly way) is very fast (~3ms); unfortunately, reading 2048 randomly chosen rows takes about 250ms. The reading part I'm trying is as follows:

```
a = f['/test']
x = []
for i in range(2048):
    r = random.randint(1,2048)
    x.append(a[[r],...])
x = np.concatenate(x, 0)
```

Clearly, the speed bottleneck is due to accessing 'a' for 2048 times because I don't know whether there exists an one-shot way of accessing to random rows or not. np.concatenate consumes a negligible amount of time. Since the matrix eventually reaches to the size of (2048*100k, 200), I probably can't use a method other than contiguous h5py. I've tried with a smaller maximal matrix size, but it didn't affect the computation time at all. For reference, the following is the entire task I'm trying to achieve as a part of deep reinforcement learning algorithm:

---

1. Generate a numpy array of size (2048, 200)
2. Write it onto the next available 2048 rows in an extendable list (None, 200)
3. Randomly pick 2048 rows from the filled rows of the extendable list (irrespective of the generated chunk in the step 1)
4. Read the picked rows
5. Continue 1-4 for 100k times (so the total list size becomes (2048*100k, 200))

Comment: My previous answer on fancy indexing, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47893697/901925.  Also if using chunking, it's best if you fetch from only one chunk at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your link! I've solved my problem as described in my reply to @davinellulinvega.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If rows can be selected more than once, I would try with:

```
random.choices(a, k=2048)
```

Otherwise, using:

```
random.sample(a, 2048)
```

Both methods will return a list of numpy arrays if **a** is an numpy ndarray.

Furthermore, if **a** is already a numpy array why not take advantage of numpy's slicing capabilities and shorten your code to:

```
x.append(a[np.randint(1, 2048, 2048)])
```

That way **a** is still accessed multiple time, but it is all done in optimized C code, which should be faster.
Hope those points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have a few remarks. For fancy indexing, you need a distinct entries with increasing order. For this, I added appropriate operations upon your numpy array at the bottom. In fact, as the link of @hpaulj above says, fancy indexing of 2048 entries makes the things slower, which made the process not faster than my method. So, I cut the your numpy array to 8 arrays with the same length and repeated the fancy indexing 8 times, which gave me x6 speedup!

Comment: That is quite interesting I was no aware of this slowness when using fancy indexing of this amplitude. Thank you for pointing that out.